# DT RowReorder extension issue in R

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I recently updated the DT package in R from version 0.2 to 0.4 and am struggling to get the 'RowReorder' extension to work. For a minimal example:

```
DT::datatable(iris, 
       colnames = c(ID = 1), 
       extensions = 'RowReorder',    
       options = list(rowReorder = TRUE, order = c(0,"asc"))
       )
```

This was working well in the previous version but after the update rows can't be reordered by clicking and dragging. I also noticed that the extension doesn't appear to be functioning properly on the documentation page found in example 9 here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

I've tried going through the documentation on the recent updates but couldn't find anything that addressed the RowReorder extension. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be very appreciated and until then I'll keep using the prior version of DT.

Thanks!!